# Using results of find to index into multi-dimensional matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-indexing

```
A = 100 x 3 matrix
B = 200 x 10 x 100 matrix
```

column 2 of A contains index to dimension 1 of B.

column 3 of A contains 2 possible values: 0 or 1.

Based on the following conditions, I want to extract the values in B.

```
x = find(A(:, 3) == 0);
y = find(A(:, 3) == 1);
```

The index to dimension 1 of B is:

```
x_idx = A(x, 2);
y_idx = A(y, 2);
```

How can I get a 2-d matrix, such that:

```
C = B(x_idx, :, x);
D = B(y_idx, :, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you -

```
ind1 = sub2ind(size(B), x_idx, ones(numel(x),1), x)
C = B(bsxfun(@plus,ind1,size(B,1)*[0:size(B,2)-1])') %%//'

ind2 = sub2ind(size(B), y_idx, ones(numel(y),1), y)
D = B(bsxfun(@plus,ind2,size(B,1)*[0:size(B,2)-1])')
```